# Find and Replace in Notepad++ for the multiple instance of search string

Tags: notepad++

I need to find and replace in multiple files in the same directory(Aware of Find in Files tab) for the below scenario in Notepad++.

**File1 Find:**

```
1. REM INSERTING INTO TABLE1
2. SET DEFINE OFF;
3. INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(....);
```

**File1 Replace:**

```
1. REM INSERTING INTO TABLE1
2. SET DEFINE OFF;
3. CALL CUSTOM_PACK.PROC_NAME('TABLE1');
4. INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(....);
5. COMMIT;
6. CALL CUSTOM_PACK.PROC_NAME('TABLE1');
```

**File2 Find:**

```
1. REM INSERTING INTO TABLE2
2. SET DEFINE OFF;
3. INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES(....);
```

**File2 Replace:**

```
1. REM INSERTING INTO TABLE2
2. SET DEFINE OFF;
3. CALL CUSTOM_PACK.PROC_NAME('TABLE2');
4. INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES(....);
5. COMMIT;
6. CALL CUSTOM_PACK.PROC_NAME('TABLE2');
```

and so on... Whereas New line 3,5,6 should be auto generated from TABLENAME.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried and how did it work? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each file, you may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    1\. REM INSERTING INTO (\w+)\R2\. SET DEFINE OFF;\R3\. INSERT INTO \1 VALUES\(\.\.\.\.\);
Replace: 1. REM INSERTING INTO $1\n2. SET DEFINE OFF;\n3. CALL CUSTOM_PACK.PROC_NAME\('$1'\);\n4. INSERT INTO $1 VALUES\(....\);\n5. COMMIT;\n6. CALL CUSTOM_PACK.PROC_NAME\('$1'\);
```

For an explanation, the pattern captures the table name from the first line, and then uses that table name when building the new lines.